# What is the type signature for a method returning type id, with no args

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

What is the type signature for a method returning type id, with no args?

Example:

```
class_addMethod(self, sel, imp, "?????"); <---- Require correct type sig here
```

Comment: BTW:  Pretty much nothing uses the type signature outside of language bridges.

Comment: @bbum - Thx for the insight. I noticed it seems to work whatever I put.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"@@:"`, I think?

> Since the function must take at least two arguments—`self` and `_cmd`, the
>   second and third characters must be “@:” (the first character is the
>   return type).

Comment: To explain with reference to the self and _cmd internals was helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `IMP` looks like

```
id some_imp(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    //return nil;
}
```

`"@@:"` is correct (return an object, take an object and a SEL).

For more type encodings, see the [runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod).